# Drain queue with timeout

Tags: java, multithreading, queue

I have a process where multiple producers populate queue and single consumer processes data it retrieves from this queue.

To improve efficiency consumer drains data from queue using `BlockingQueue#drainTo` API. There is one problem though, when queue is empty consumer will try to drain data in a loop without delays consuming a lot of CPU.

Is there API which allows to drain queue with timeout similar to `BlockingQueue#poll(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)`?

Sample consumer code:

```
while (threadIsActive) {
    List<Event> events = new ArrayList<>();
    queue.drainTo(events);
    processEvents(events);
}
```

Comment: So your approach ended up worsening the performance.

Comment: Not really, most of the time queue is not empty and this approach improves high load period processing. Now I want to improve CPU consumption when system is not under load.

Comment: Then do a `poll()` when the queue is empty.

Comment: I think i am not clear but want to know that why consumer will try to drain data in a loop if queue is empty?

Comment: Because it may be empty now and it will have data on the next iteration, this is multithreading application and you never know when data is published to the queue. So you have to constantly check queue using either blocking or non-blocking API.

Comment: Guava Queues.drain is a good alternative:
[https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Queues.html#drain(java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue, java.util.Collection, int, long, java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)](https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Queues.html#drain(java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue,%20java.util.Collection,%20int,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using poll/drainTo combination which was suggested by @Kayaman, I do not like it very much, it looks ugly. But I will accept any other answer which proposes better solution:

```
while (threadIsActive) {
    Event firstEvent = queue.poll(queuePollTimeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    if (firstEvent != null) {
        // reserve enough space to fit first event, current queue capacity and
        // new events which occur while we are draining
        int drainCapacity = queue.size() * 2;
        List<Event> events = new ArrayList<>(drainCapacity);

        events.add(firstEvent);
        queue.drainTo(events);

        processEvents(events);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I agree with @Kayaman, as `BlockingQueue#drainTo` API is non-blocking API, so in this case we can use `BlockingQueue#poll(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)` API for your task. May be you can write some kind of below code:

```
    while (threadIsActive) {
        List<Event> events = new ArrayList<>();
        events.add(queue.poll(timeout, TimeUnit.SECONDS))  //Block until queue is EMPTY
        queue.drainTo(events);
        processEvents(events);
    }
```